# How to jump back to the cursor position before I entered insert mode?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, cursor-motions

I'm trying to set up normal mode mappings to make it easy to add white space around the cursor:

`<C-h>` will add one space to the right of the cursor;
`<C-j>` will add a newline below;
`<C-k>` will add a newline above;
`<C-l>` will add one space to the right of the cursor; and
`<C-Enter>` will add a newline at the current cursor position.

I also want the cursor position not to move during the command. For left, right, and newline, this is simple:

```
nnoremap <C-h> i <Esc>l
nnoremap <C-l> a <Esc>h
nnoremap <C-^M> i<CR><Esc><Backspace>
```

but for above and below, the corresponding commands

```
nnoremap <C-j> o <Esc>k
nnoremap <C-k> O <Esc>j
```

will get me back on the right line, but not back to the same column that I was on before.

Is there any way to return to the cursor position I was at just before entering insert mode? My best Google-fu only brought up references to `''` & double-backtick (can't figure out how to format the markdown there) and `:jumps` / `<C-O>` & `<C-I>`, neither of which seem to work quite the way I'd like.

Can this be solved without Vimscript? Can it even be solved *with* Vimscript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a local mark to where you're before opening a new line, and go back to this mark afterwards.

You can choose any letter for the mark, let's say for example `x`:

```
nnoremap <C-k> mxO<esc>`x
nnoremap <C-j> mxo<esc>`x
```

- `mx` sets the mark `x` where the cursor is
- `` `x `` moves the cursor back to the position of mark `x`

You could also look at what tpope wrote in his [unimpaired plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/master/plugin/unimpaired.vim) and put the following code inside your vimrc:

```
set nostartofline

function! s:BlankUp(count) abort
  put!=repeat(nr2char(10), a:count)
  ']+1
endfunction

function! s:BlankDown(count) abort
  put =repeat(nr2char(10), a:count)
  '[-1
endfunction

nnoremap <c-k> :<c-u>call <SID>BlankUp(v:count1)<cr>
nnoremap <c-j> :<c-u>call <SID>BlankDown(v:count1)<cr>
```

The advantage of this solution over the previous one is that it accepts a count and doesn't change any of your marks.
For example to insert 2 lines above the current one, hit `2<C-k>`, 3 lines below `3<C-j>`.

PS: to write a double backtick in your post, use triple backticks before and after (and put spaces before and after the double backtick):
``` `` ```

**Edit**
I just noticed that in the case of the 2nd solution, if you want the cursor to come back to the same column where it was before pasting a new line, you have to disable the option `'startofline'`: `set nostartofline`

When this option is disabled, the column number of your cursor stays the same after using various commands such as `<C-d>`, `gg`, `dd`, `>>`, `:bnext`, `:25`.
See `:help 'startofline'` for more info.

Answer (score 7):

No need for vimscript here, the mappings below do exactly what you ask:

```
nnoremap <C-j> m`o<Esc>``
nnoremap <C-k> m`O<Esc>``
```

- `` m` `` is used to set the "previous context mark",
- `o<Esc>` does what you expect,
- ``` `` ``` jumps back to the previous context mark.

Comment: Also note that you can also use `m'` and `''` instead of `m\`` and `\`\``

Comment: @EvergreenTree, `''` won't jump to the right column, only to the right line.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that.